# Separate Pandas Dataframe row in multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe that represents an organigram with 11 levels that looks like this:

| level0 | level1 | level2 | level3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Emma | John | Jason |  |
| Emma | John | Hamza | Michael |
| Emma | John | Hamza | Olivia |
| Emma | Adam | Jaber |  |
| Emma | Adam | Noah |  |
| Emma | Catherine | Kate | Frank |

My desired output would look like this, where each new column cell is separated to a new row:

| level0 | level1 | level2 | level3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Emma |  |  |  |
|  | John |  |  |
|  |  | Jason |  |
|  |  | Hamza |  |
|  |  |  | Michael |
|  |  |  | Olivia |
|  | Adam |  |  |
|  |  | Jaber |  |
|  |  | Noah |  |
|  | Catherine |  |  |
|  |  | Kate |  |
|  |  |  | Frank |

Using pandas.shift I've been able to get this dataframe:

| level0 | level1 | level2 | level3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Emma | John | Jason |  |
|  |  | Hamza | Michael |
|  |  |  | Olivia |
|  | Adam | Jaber |  |
|  |  | Noah |  |
|  | Catherine | Kate | Frank |

But I can't find a way to add the needed depth. Any suggestions?

Here's my code:

````
shifted_organigram= organigram.shift(1)
final_organigram=organigram[organigram.loc[:]!=shifted_organigram.loc[:]]
final_organigram = final_organigram.fillna("")```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use `melt` at starting point to flatten your dataframe and `pivot` at the end to reshape it:

```
out = (
    df.replace('', np.nan)
      .melt(ignore_index=False)
      .drop_duplicates('value')
      .sort_index()
      .assign(index=lambda x: range(len(x)))
      .pivot('index', 'variable', 'value')
      .fillna('')
      .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
)
```

You can execute this statements one by one from top to bottom to follow the transformation, i.e. `df.replace(...)` then `df.replace(...).melt(...)` and so on.

Output:

```
>>> out
   level0     level1 level2   level3
0    Emma                           
1               John                
2                     Jason         
3                                   
4                     Hamza         
5                            Michael
6                             Olivia
7               Adam                
8                     Jaber         
9                      Noah         
10         Catherine                
11                     Kate         
12                             Frank
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't work at first, the order wasn't respected. I made it work by modifying it like this:

out = (
    sorted_organigram.replace('', np.nan)
      .melt(ignore_index=False)
      .drop_duplicates('value')
      .rename_axis('MyIdx')
      .sort_values(by=['MyIdx','variable'])
      .assign(index=lambda x: range(len(x)))
      .pivot('index', 'variable', 'value')
      .fillna('')
      .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
)